# A definition for relativistic energy without quantum mechanics

Tags: special-relativity, energy

What are the minimal postulates to define energy in special relativity?

Let us assume that momentum has not been defined yet (it can be defined from the energy in fact).

I expect we are looking for a positive conserved quantity. But this is not enough right?

Do we need to postulate that energy is Doppler shifted in the case of a photon? But basically that would be assuming energy is frequency (E=hv), thus requiring knowledge of quantum mechanics. From there I know it is possible to define energy (to an arbitrary factor) and derive all the usual Lorentz transforms, but it seems a little disappointing to require quantum mechanics knowledge here.

Is there another simple postulate that would be sufficient?

Comment: energy is "Doppler shifted" for massive particles as well: it is a simple consequence of Lorentz transformations. No need of QM for this whatsoever.

Comment: Yes indeed energy is doppler shifted for any particle, but why? This is not a consequence of Lorentz transformations: they are merely equivalent to Doppler shift.

Comment: I beg to differ: the transformation properties of energy **are** a consequence of Lorentz transformations. See, for example http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/vec4.html#c2

Comment: Well, that's a good point, but I'm reading a lesson book by Malcolm Ludvigsen, who proves the reverse: defining the energy as the frequency, he proves first the Doppler effect from the relativity postulate, then proves the existence and unicity of the four-momentum, and finally derives the Lorentz transformations. From that, I conclude that the two approaches are equivalent, but they both seem to require some assumption on the form of the energy or the momentum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot defined energy on its own in special relativity. It is just not a proper Lorentz invariant quantity, you have to work with the 4-momentum which is invariant as a tensor (and consists of the energy and the spatial momentum). The correct way to define (point-mechanical) 4-momentum (that is: energy and momentum) in special relativity is by an application of the [Noether theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem):

> 4-momentum is the conserved quantity that arises due to the space-time translation invariance of the theory in (Minkowski) space-time.

If you consider a classical field theory you will have to define energy density as the 00-component of the stress-energy tensor (so the notion of energy is again not Lorentz invariant). The stress-energy tensor can again be understood as quantity conserved due to the space-time translation invariance, the associated conservation law is:
$$ T^{\mu\nu}_{,\mu} = 0$$
which gives four continuity equations, one for the energy density and three for the spatial momentum components. Again, while the stress-energy tensor and its associated conservation law are Lorentz invariant, energy conservation is not, but only holds in a fixed coordinate system.

Note, that special relativity is just a framework, you have to consider some theory in the framework set by special relativity to get concrete expressions for the energy. That is: special relativity requires a theory (e.g. relativistic mechanics, electrodynamics, some relativistic theory of a classical scalar field) to be Lorentz invariant. The Lorentz symmetry and translational symmetry (that is 
Poincaré symmetry) then has associated conserved quantities due to the Noether theorem, and one of those is 4-momentum.

---

By the way: The correct way to construct energy, momentum and angular momentum in *any* theory is to identify the conserved quantities due to space-time translation symmetry resp. rotation symmetry.

A further note: Of course you can construct a conserved energy *in a fixed reference frame* for time translation invariant systems, even if spatial translation symmetry is broken. You just have to be careful, that while this quantity will help you solve the problem, it is not an invariant quantity, that has a observer independent meaning. Also, you can extend this to a non-conserved energy when considering time dependent external forces (just as it is done in classical mechanics).

Comment: Using time invariance to define energy requires to postulate the form of the Lagrangian, right? So that does not ultimately answer the question (what would be the definition of the Lagrangian then?). If I understand your overall point, you're saying that the definition of energy is theory-dependent. That sounds reasonable. But then, what defines energy in relativistic point mechanics?

Comment: The Lagrangian for relativistic point mechanics (for a free particle) is simply $L = -mc \int dt \sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\dot x^\mu \dot x^\nu} = -mc \int ds$ (the factor is convention, $m$ denotes the invariant mass).

Comment: This definition of the Lagrangian involves mass, whereas in the book I'm reading (by Malcolm Ludvigsen), mass is defined as the minimum energy that the particle could take by change of frame. Thus mass is derived from the energy. Then you could actually derive this Lagrangian. This seems to be the reverse approach that you are taking. Ludvigsen's book starts from E=hv and derives all about the Lorentz transforms. However, if you start from the Lagrangian, could you derive E=hv ?! Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe I spoke too fast. The Lagrangian can be defined to an arbitrary factor. The lagrange equations basically represent the fact that the "distance" a particle actually takes between two events is the smallest. The remaining factor is defined as the rest mass. Thus I guess that the answer is ultimately that the lagrange equations give energy a behaviour similar to the inverse of time (frequency), which (surprisingly?) coincides with the quantum mechanical E=hv.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound super boring, but you define it the same was as in Newtonian Physics.

You start with particles and force and talk about work done. This changes the energy of the particle. But you want energy to be conserved.

So what's the problem? The problem is you didn't want to bring up momentum, so really you couldn't bring up force. And that is a problematic arbitrary constraint in Newtonian dynamics and problematic arbitrary constraint in special relativity.

But at least in special relativity you can do conservation of energy properly. Instead of the whole potential energy lie, you can literally just have a conserved energy. For instance when a charged particle gains or loses kinetic energy you have the fields lose or gain an equal amount of energy.

And it happens locally. The power gain of the particle and the power lose of the fields are equal and they happen in the same place, the location of the charge.

And you can figure out how fields change in different frames (to make Maxwell look the same in all frames) and you get how energy density changes and momentum density for free.

So work and conservation of energy tell you about the field energy and knowing how fields changes tells you how energy density changes. From that you can then get momentum.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. Are you saying you need to start with electromagnetism to define energy?